# on_member_join event discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I maked an auto roles giving system with `on_member_join` event, it has worked until now, now it's not sending messages to members, and not giving roles. Please help:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    Role1 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 723244173779533925)
    await member.add_roles(Role1)
    Role2 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 723244271628582962)
    await member.add_roles(Role2)
    Role3 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 723563998393663499)
    await member.add_roles(Role3)
    await member.send('Hi, welcome to my server! In 30 seconds i will give you verified role, please **read rules** in that time.')
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
    verifiedRole = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 788393533874765855)
    await member.add_roles(verifiedRole)
    await member.send('I given you the verified role, and you have access to the rest of the guild.')
```

Comment: hi, does it throw any exception?

Comment: No, it's not. Just don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need intents.

You'll need to add this code above your definition of `bot`:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

Now, add the `intents=intents` parameter to your bot initialization underneath the intents bit:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
# If you have commands.Bot, add `intents = intents` in the parentheses:
bot = commands.Bot(your_options_here,intents = intents)
# If you have discord.Client(), add `intents = intents` into the parentheses:
bot = discord.Client(intents = intents)
```

Make sure you enable the members intent in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers).
You can read up on intents more [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).